# WPF Dynamic Image For TabItem Header

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I'm currently developing a WPF form that contains a tab control with multiple tabs.

An example of an individual tab header:

```
<TabItem.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Primary " />
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=PrimaryImage}" />        
    </StackPanel>
</TabItem.Header>
```

I'm trying to set the tab header image based on whether that relative tab contains any data within it.

My code:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PrimaryImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PrimaryImage", typeof(string), typeof(TabControl));

    public string PrimaryImage
       {
          get { return (string)GetValue(PrimaryImageProperty); }
          set { SetValue(PrimaryImageProperty, value); }
       }

     if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tabData)
       {
          PrimaryImage = "/MyForm;component/Resources/tick-button-icon.png";
       }
     else
       {
          PrimaryImage = "/MyForm;component/Resources/grey-button-icon.png";
       }
```

However when I run the application, the image is not set/displayed.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you register the property in tabcontrol but tabitem are binded to the chidren tabitem collection..??

```
PrimaryImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PrimaryImage", typeof(string), typeof(TabControl));
```

Comment: I'm trying to add an image next each tab header text to illustrate whether that tab contains any information. The code I used above seemed the closest fit for my problem, but happy to take a different route to achieve the outcome!

Comment: well, if you were MVVM, i would have added tabitemviewmodels with a property to the tab item collection; if hard coded...? where does the tabData comes from ? how do you decide to display one image or another 
 - it is in the tab control ?

Comment: Happy to move to a MVVM, but not sure how to do that. The number of tabs are fixed (4). The logic to determine whether a tab is populated or not is done through some SQL logic and my intention was to have a boolean function to decide which image to display on the tab header.

Comment: Moving to MVVM will be complicated. From the SQL logic you can set the tag property of your tabitems, and make a binding to it in the header : <Image Source="{Binding Path=Tag}" />; either use a converter for tag to image or put the image path directly

Comment: Would that be along the lines of `public class ImageDisplayConvertor : IValueConverter`

Comment: yes, look at that if you need samples : https://github.com/TheCamel/CBR/tree/master/CBR/Components/Converters